# Buffer error in ROS melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, buffer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

This code fragment is perfectly working in ROS kinetic:

```
 tf::TransformListener tf_(ros::Duration(10));
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS willow_garage_costmap("willowgarage_costmap", tf_);
```

However, in ROS melodic, it gives error, I searched for it and tried to solve it by changing to:

```
 tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer;
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS willow_garage_costmap("willowgarage_costmap", tfBuffer);
```

But, this gives error:

**Do not call canTransform or lookupTransform with a timeout unless you are using another thread for populating data. Without a dedicated thread it will always timeout. If you have a seperate thread servicing tf messages, call setUsingDedicatedThread(true) on your Buffer instance.**

I think it is an issue with Buffer constructor, but I don't know how to fix it?

Help highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390634/buffer-error-in-ros-melodic/) by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-11**:
Could you display the original error without changing to `tfBuffer`?

**Comment by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on 2021-11-11**:
If I use:

```
tf::TransformListener tf_(ros::Duration(10));
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS willow_garage_costmap("willowgarage_costmap", tf_);
```

I got:

1-

**error: no matching function for call to ‘costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::Costmap2DROS(const char [21], tf::TransformListener&)’ costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS willow_garage_costmap("willowgarage_costmap", tf_);**

2-

**note: candidate: costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::Costmap2DROS(const string&, tf2_ros::Buffer&) Costmap2DROS(const std::string &name, tf2_ros::Buffer& tf);**

3-

**note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘tf::TransformListener’ to ‘tf2_ros::Buffer&’**

**Comment by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on 2021-11-11**:
As described above, I got an error and 2 notes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS melodic, this fix the problem:

```
  tf2_ros::Buffer tfBuffer(ros::Duration(10));
  tf2_ros::TransformListener tfListener(tfBuffer);
  costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS willow_garage_costmap("willowgarage_costmap", tfBuffer);
```

---

Originally posted by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) with karma: 65 on 2021-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0